# Why am I receiving "[Errno 22] Invalid argument" in the following when using PdfFileReader/How can I do the below better?

Tags: python, pypdf

I have a list of file directories for pdfs that I'd like to join together and am trying to use a for-loop to add each of these efficiently into the PdfFileReader function. I know the below code doesn't work and produces the above error, so any advice on how to avoid this error/achieve the desired result better would be welcome and much appreciated!

```
**file_list = [x,y,z,...] # x, y and z are the file paths...

pdf_list = []

for i in file_list:
        pdf = PdfFileReader(i, "rb")
        pdf_list.append(pdf)**
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because the `"rb"` doesn't belong there.

However, it's hard to tell. In future, you should add...

- the exact version you're using
- the Traceback
- A complete code (including imports + the file that causes the issue)